# How to properly underline blank space after text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to underline the space after a heading in Microsoft Word. I have managed to fake it by using some `_` underscore characters like so.

[image: Underline example]

However, I would like the line to appear higher so it is in line with the baseline of the text instead of just below it. If I use a border, I can see that it's possible to adjust the underline position but the border then gets applied to the whole line instead of the space after the text.

Comment: Assuming you are building a document for someone to complete ... Putting an underline along any open space in a paragraph will only work if you are printing the document and someone then fills it in with a pencil or pen. If they are to complete the form by typing, then you should use a text box content control or a table cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the TAB character. Then you can use the normal underline in Word on your tabulators. You can control the length of the underline by [placing a tab stop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/set-tab-stops-and-paragraph-indents-in-microsoft-word-34361115-2b5a-9fcc-2d34-9d7c9e007b71).